# Github asking for login and password

Tags: git, github

I was recently informed by Github that my personal access token needs regeneration.
I clicked the link provided in the mail and it appeared to be successful. I copied the token they gave me and told me tha I won’t be seeing it again.
I do not know what am I supposed to with that token.
However the first time I tried to push something after that I was prompted to enter my login credentials. I never used that before. I have my ssh key. And login and password I enter when I get prompted are invalid.

On one of my repos I manually I went into .git folder, config file and changed remote url to the ssh url I have on my github profile, and it worked.
So my question: Is this a bad practice, and is there another way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using a GitHub personal access token and are prompted for t ausername and password, the username is your username, and the password is the personal access token, not your password.  The way that Git performs authentication over HTTPS is called Basic authentication, and the two parts of those credentials are usually called a username and password even if a token is used, which is why Git refers to those terms.  It can't distinguish the two.

It is also secure to use SSH authentication if you prefer.  Both HTTPS and SSH authentication are considered secure, and SSH is actually a little better because it doesn't send private material at all.  You can use whichever one you like, though.